# sharing text on "facebook Page" in ios from our app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook page, and i want to share some text on that page just like my status as we share on our "me/feed" from our application.

Please someone suggest how i should go about it?

Answer (score 0):

for iOS 6.0 you can do something like that:

```
    NSString *text1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", NSLocalizedString(@"Check out this nice'... ", @""), self.title];
    NSString *text2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", NSLocalizedString(@"in", @""), self.restaurant.title];
    NSString *text3 = NSLocalizedString(@"Sent from FoodRock Menus App", @"");
    NSURL *appURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://testappstorelink.com"];
    NSArray *activityItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:text1, text2, text3, appURL, photo, nil];
    UIActivityViewController *actVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems
                                                                        applicationActivities:nil];
    actVC.excludedActivityTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
                                   UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, nil];
    actVC.completionHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed){
        DLog(@"ACTIVITYTYPE: %@ FINISHED: %@", activityType, completed ? @"YES" : @"NO");
        if (completed) {
            NSString *socialString = @"";
            if ([activityType containsSubstring:@"PostToTwitter"]) {
                socialString = @"Twitter";
            } else if ([activityType containsSubstring:@"PostToFacebook"]) {
                socialString = @"Facebook";
            } else if ([activityType containsSubstring:@"Message"]) {
                socialString = @"Message";
            } else if ([activityType containsSubstring:@"Mail"]) {
                socialString = @"Mail";
            }
            [[FRNWAchievementsController controller] reportSocialShareEvent:socialString menuItem:self];
        }
    };
    return actVC;
```

Comment: I dont want it on my live feed, but on facebook Page.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some code snippets to help you out, but you should also have a look at the Facebook developer examples which are pretty good.

```
        // To log in to Facebook with permission to post...
        m_Facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:YOUR_FACEBOOK_APPID
                                     andDelegate:self];
        m_FacebookPermissions = [[NSArray 
            arrayWithObjects:/*@"read_stream",*/ @"publish_stream", nil] retain];
        [m_Facebook authorize:m_FacebookPermissions];
```

And in some other method after the fbDidLogin callback tells you you're logged in:

```
// After successful login…
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary  dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               WHAT_YOU_WANT_TO_SAY, @"message",
                            nil];
[m_Facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed"
                      andParams:params
                  andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                    andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: I dont want it on my live feed, but on facebook Page. Zzz